# How to accurately count multiple emails being sent in Rails Cucumber Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, actionmailer

I have a Cucumber test that drives out someone completing a form, the output of which should be two emails (one to the user, one to an admin).

### Setup

Following [this guide](http://stevelorek.com/actionmailer-cucumber.html) I have set up a wrapper around any scenario marked `@email`.

```
Around('@email') do |_scenario, block|
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
  ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
  block.call
end
```

`ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test` was already set in my `config/environments/test.rb` file.

The scenario looks something like this (edited to remove business wording)

```
@email
Scenario: Can find out more
  Given I am a visitor
  When I visit a page
  And I complete the form
  Then I should get an email, as should the admin
```

The related definitions are;

```
When(/^I complete the form$/) do
  fill_in('Email Address', with: 'test@test.com')
  fill_in('Name', with: 'Test Name')
  click_button('Subscribe')
end

Then(/^I should get an email, as should the admin$/) do
  expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size).to eq 2
end
```

### The Code

This code works when doing a dry run locally, just not under test.

```
def subscribe
  SubscribeMailer.user_subscribe(params[:email]).deliver_later

  SubscribeMailer.subscribe_email(params[:name],
                                  params[:email],
                                  request.referrer).deliver_later
  redirect_to subscribe_thanks_path
end
```

The `user_subscribe` and `subscribe_email` just make some instance variables and call `mail`.

Throwing some debuggers around I can see all parts of the system I would expect to get hit appear to do so.

### Expected result

I would expect this to always send two emails (or zero emails in the case of me doing something wrong).

### Actual result

What I get back is consistently 1 email.

The email I get back is the `user_subscribe` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I'm using Rails 5 and between 4 and 5 the default behaviour of `config.active_job.queue_adapter` changed.

Adding `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline` into `config/environments/test.rb` fixed this issue. It now accurately counts the emails sent.